# Неправильная кодировка при отправке письма (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, MailMessage)

Tags: c#, .net-core, .netcore2.0

Есть код отправки письма через

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, MailMessage
>   .
>   Net.Core 2.
>   Отправка писем через почтовые сервера goole.com.

Казалось-бы что может быть проще.
Но: 
При работе кода на Win10 - Все ок.
При работе кода под Ubuntu - кодировка письма не UTF-8 а что-то другое почему-то.
Вот так приходит:

> ...������ ����...

и в заголовке письма и в теле.

Пробовал играться параметрами:
HeadersEncoding, SubjectEncoding, BodyEncoding, BodyTransferEncoding - не помогает.

Пробовал библиотеку MailKit - ровно то-же самое: под win10 все ок, под linux - кракозябры.

Т.е. проблема именно где-то в связке Net.Core 2 - Linux.

Может кто подскажет направление куда копать?

Comment: Попробуйте включить логгирование `System.Net`, возможно там будут отображены все `SMTP` команды и данные. А дальше сравните работающую версию и неработающую.

Comment: Включал - разницы в логах нет ни байт :)

Comment: Не может такого быть

Comment: Я имею в виду в части отправки писем.

Comment: Я не сильно понимаю, что вы там логгировали. Если посмотреть Stmp сессию, должна быть какая-то разница.

Comment: Я включаю логирование так:
loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace);
loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Trace);
Этот лог имелся в виду?
Если он то в нм по SMTP одна строчка - "SmtpClient: Send..(и далее инфо об адресе)"
И все.

Или вы имели в виду перехват IP трафика?

Comment: Я не в курсе как там в Core, в обычном .NET лог подключается в app.config в system.diagnostics секции. Надо логгировать весь пересылаемый трафик.

Comment: В меня есть пример лога, там есть записи вот такие: `HeaderCollection#45485984::Set(MIME-Version=1.0)`, `HeaderCollection#40016800::Set(Content-Transfer-Encoding=quoted-printable)`